How to capture logs during Xtend compilation
I’m trying to debug an issue in the Xtend compilation process and want to capture detailed logs to see:

Which classes are being compiled after the xtend:compile step.
How long each class takes to compile.

I am experiencing an issue where the Xtend compilation process hangs for around 1 hour during the xtend:compile step in Maven. after that only it starts to log the warnings.
Warning information
[2024-12-06T04:04:42.393Z] [INFO] 
[2024-12-06T04:04:42.393Z] [INFO] --- xtend-maven-plugin:2.28.0:compile (default) @ gtn.testscripts ---
[2024-12-06T05:11:51.687Z] [WARNING] 
[2024-12-06T05:11:51.687Z] WARNING:     PREPOC_UploadLookupFile.xtend - /opt/jenkins/agent/workspace/Xtend/xtend-scripts/src/preconditions/PREPOC_UploadLookupFile.xtend

Current plugin configuration:
Here's my xtend-maven-plugin setup:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.xtend</groupId>
    <artifactId>xtend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${xtend.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <generateSyntheticSuppressWarnings>false</generateSyntheticSuppressWarnings>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${xtendGenDirectory}</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.codegen</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>

Is there any way to log which classes are being compiled during the xtend:compile step, and track the time taken for each class during this phase? I'm using xtend-maven-plugin version 2.28.0
What I’ve tried:

Running Maven in debug mode (-X), but it does not show the specific details of class-level compilation.
Using the verbose and trace options in the xtend-maven-plugin configuration, but the logs only show high-level actions, not detailed file compilation.

